# JavaScript going back multiple times in history

Tags: javascript

I know to go back in history with JavaScript you use:

```
window.history.back();
```

But how can I go back multiple times.

e.g. to go back 4 times I tried:

```
window.history.back().back().back().back();
```

But it didn't work. How can I go back multiple times in history with JavaScript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history (note HTML5)

Comment: Why downvote? I was only asking something I want to know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i = number of pages you want to go back

```
window.history.go(-i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `history.go(-4)`. Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History)