# history.back() Not Working When Navigating Back on Same Domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, compatibility

I would like to implement a function that ensures prompting back on all browsers to stay within a given domain, and avoid skipping back too far in history.

This is my current progress:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    if (document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.host) !== -1) {
        history.back();
    }
});
</script>
```

And this is what I implemented previously:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener("load",function(event){
    var historyTraversal=event.persisted||
    (typeof window.performance!=="undefined"&&
    window.performance.navigation.type===2);
    if(historyTraversal){
        window.history.back();
    }
});

</script>
```

Is there any significant difference between these 2 scripts?

Comment: They don't look anything alike, they are significantly different. You need to specify what you have tried and didn't work and any concerns. Just generic requests for improving code are too broad for a question on SO

Comment: In the first script, I've attempted to create an updated version of the second script, which contains deprecated content.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to implement a function that ensures prompting back on all browsers to stay within a given domain, and avoid skipping back too far in history.

It seems like what you have written is an event listener for when the window loads. When do you want to use the function you speak of?

Right now, the first script you provide executes a function [on window load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event). The function checks [the referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) (the URL of the page that linked to the current page), and if the current hostname *is* in that referrer URL (i.e. [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns some value other than -1, indicating a match), then the browser goes back.

Assuming this load handler is present, on each page load, the browser would go back until the referrer does not contain the current hostname.

I can't tell that this does exactly what you want, however - and it depends on each page you go back to having the load handler function defined.

To answer your second question:

> Is there any significant difference between these 2 scripts?

In the second script you listed you also have an event handler for the window load event, but instead of comparing the hostname to the referrer, the second handler depends on deprecated functionality. The [PerformanceNavigation type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type) is checked, and if it's `2` (indicating the current page was navigated to by going "back" through history), then it goes back.

Major differences between these two approaches:

- the first function goes back based on domain, whereas the second function does not look at the domain at all
- the second function relies on deprecated functionality, whereas the first function is a bit more straightforward
- the second function will go back as long as the current page was reached by going back, whereas the first function will go back only as long as the previous page is the same domain as the current one

It seems like the first function is more aligned with what you say you want, but neither seem like particularly good ways to go about this, considering the referrer will be empty if the user went to the link using a bookmark or typing it directly in the browser (i.e., wasn't referred to the page by a link).

It might be better, instead, if you can keep track in a cookie or other session based storage, keep track of how many pages forward the user is from the initial page you want to go back to, and then use `history.go(-n)` to go back that many pages `n` you have kept track of. (See: [JavaScript going back multiple times in history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641154/javascript-going-back-multiple-times-in-history)).

This of course would introduce its own problems, particularly what happens if the user goes away from your domain and then back - figuring out how to keep an accurate count so it always goes back to the most recent initial instance of a URL with your domain would be the next step.

Comment: thank you for your very extensive and in-depth answer. The main reason I am trying to implement this type of code is because of a framework issue with a third-party site (Tumblr), which has a bug that doesn't load the previous page when prompting back on mobile browsers, but instead reloads the current page over and over again. I am trying to override this, and the second script does resolves the mobile issue, but I was attempting to implement something without deprecated contents, so I am kind of left in a quandary...

Comment: No problem - glad to help! When the user is trying to go back, is the user on Tumblr (and Tumblr just reloads instead of going back), or is the user on your site and trying to go back to Tumblr and the history no longer works so it reloads your page? I'm unclear on the actual use-case here. It seems to me it will be hard for you to override what Tumblr does, since you can't inject code into their pages. Are you working with iframes or an embedded Tumblr page or something?

Comment: I have posted a question previously, which describes essentially the same issue at hand. Here's a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783447/window-history-back-navigation-issue-on-firefox. I have a demo site which shows the issue partially resolved, but there is still some functionality issues with Firefox (desktop browser).

Comment: I can't go to [your demo site](https://www.testblog123098.tumblr.com/) because you have an SSL error that blocks me: `SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN`:

"Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for www.testblog123098.tumblr.com. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.tumblr.com, tumblr.com"